# Excel Cumulative decrease

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate a Cumulative decrease depending on two parameters: years and percentage. To explain my need, in the following image there is a table with the results by year. I need a formula to put this table in one single cell (ending value)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution but I've made this home-made polynomial formula that will work for 10 years, after that you may need to adjust it:

Please arrange your summary table like in my picture (observe row number and column) and put the formula below into your Ending Value cell (B11):

```
=B8 * 
IF( B9=1, 1,
 IF( B9=2, 1+B10,
   IF( B9=3, 1+B10+B10^2,
    IF( B9=4, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3,
        IF( B9=5, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4,
          IF( B9=6, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4+B10^5,
            IF( B9=7, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4+B10^5+B10^6,
              IF( B9=8, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4+B10^5+B10^6+B10^7,
                IF( B9=9, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4+B10^5+B10^6+B10^7+B10^8,
                  IF( B9=10, 1+B10+B10^2+B10^3+B10^4+B10^5+B10^6+B10^7+B10^8+B10^9, "formula works max for 10 years"   ))))))))))
```

N.B. YEARS MUST BE whole numbers for the formula to work

[image: ARRANGE THE TABLE FROM CELL A8]

Comment: very usefull. Thanks!